# zend_mail email marked as spam in 4th try

Tags: zend-framework, smtp, gmail, html-email, zend-mail

i am using zend_mail as html to send an email confirmation to the server, for the 1st and the 2nd test the message was forwarded to inbox but then suddenly all messages where marked as spam. this is the php code:

```
$mails = '<div style = "background-color:#6BC6D3;">

<div style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 33px auto auto;
width: 400px;
padding : 20px; 
direction: rtl;
font: 15px tahoma">
www
<br />
<br />
اtestetstststtestxs
<br />
testetstststtestxsx
<br />
<br />
<a href="http://forid.ir/user/confirm/123109231109203912">http://forid.ir/user/confirm/123109231109203912</a>

</div>
</div>

 ';
$config = array('auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'info@forid.ir',
                'password' => '*******',);

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('mail.forid.ir', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('info@forid.ir', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('sjhh.206@gmail.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->setBodyHtml($mails,"utf8");
$mail->setBodyText($mails);
$mail->send($transport);
```

and this is my email in details

> Delivered-To: sjhh.206@gmail.com Received: by 10.100.120.8 with SMTP id s8csp160566anc;        Sat, 19 May 2012 06:21:50 -0700 (PDT)
>   Received: by 10.216.144.216 with SMTP id
>   n66mr9808634wej.107.1337433710571;
>           Sat, 19 May 2012 06:21:50 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path:  Received: from server6g.axspace.com ([176.9.63.137])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id s62si1351562weh.54.2012.05.19.06.21.50
>           (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
>           Sat, 19 May 2012 06:21:50 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@forid.ir designates 176.9.63.137 as
>   permitted sender) client-ip=176.9.63.137; Authentication-Results:
>   mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@forid.ir
>   designates 176.9.63.137 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=info@forid.ir
>   Message-Id:
>   <4fb79e6e.547ad80a.7d62.ffff8455SMTPIN_ADDED@mx.google.com> Received:
>   from server6g.axspace.com ([176.9.63.137] helo=localhost)     by
>   server6g.axspace.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.76)  (envelope-from
>   )  id 1SVjbp-0001po-S0     for sjhh.206@gmail.com; Sat, 19
>   May 2012 15:22:13 +0200 From: Some Sender  To: Some
>   Recipient  Subject: TestSubject Date: Sat, 19 May
>   2012 15:22:13 +0200 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
>   boundary="=_39a92918883006684b860d22bac01025" MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> --=_39a92918883006684b860d22bac01025 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

i have no idea why it is marked as spam, and i have no idea how to fix it, i used to think using smtp mail would solve the spam problem but it didn't. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @David said, your spam rating has absolutely nothing to do with using `Zend_Mail`. Unless you're willing to invest a lot of time and effort into configuring your mail servers for optimal delivery, I would highly recommend outsourcing your transactional email sends. ESPs like [Sendgrid](http://go.sendgrid.com/transactional-email.html?ls=SEM&cid=70180000000cl5Z&lsd=adwords&kw=transactionalemailExact&gaid=SendGrid-US-Main&gclid=CP_w2a72jLACFQc5nAod1xAIrA), [Sailthru](https://www.sailthru.com/), and [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/?pid=GAW&source=website&gclid=CM2Y9cD2jLACFYqb7QodsF32qw) will do the job way better than you can.

Comment: it just about confirming users email ... why would it be filtered? what are the rules? searched a bit but found almost nothing .. :D

Comment: Incoming email is judged on more than just content. Common factors include html to text ratios, sender reputation, presence of reverse DNS, DKIM, domain keys etc. Probably the most important is sender reputation. This is based on the IP you're sending mail from. If, for example, the previous owner of the IP engaged in shady email practices, your sender reputation is already marred.

Answer (score 3):

Mail marked as spam almost certainly has nothing to do with the fact that the mail was composed/sent using `Zend_Mail`. Other factors like the HTML markup, the content itself, the SMTP server, and spam detection rules on the receiving side (Gmail) must be the cause.

Comment: allright i allready know that but isnt there anywhere to understand the rules on the recieving side?

Comment: The answer/comment from @ChrisHenry details some of the other general factors that could play a role. But as to specifics, remember that a receiving server that publicizes precisely how it identifies spam would assist the spammers in circumventing that detection.

Comment: One thought: remove the garbase words (ex: 'testetstststtestxsx'). Gmail may perceive a message with a single link and garbage text as some kind of spammy solicitation.